# graphql codegen typescript - how to generate types only

Tags: typescript, graphql, code-generation

I'm using the typescript plugin for graphql code generator

According to the doc

> This is the most basic TypeScript plugin and it can generate typings based on GraphQLSchema, which can be used by any other typescript related plugin.
>
> It generates types for your entire schema: types, input types, enums, interfaces, scalars and unions.

Is it possible to generate only types? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that all of the items mentioned `(types, input types, enums, interfaces, scalars and unions)` are types. If you need to generate only one of these items, unfortunately the typescript plugin currently does not support this.